# How to change color of shapes in Turtle through lists

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

I was wondering if there was a way I can make a list of colors, like `shape_color = ['red', 'blue', 'green']`, and have that list assigned to a single `onkey()` keyboard key so that whenever I press that key, it cycles through the list of colors, changing the turtle's color? My program is in Python turtle graphics where you move the cursor around stamping different shapes into the screen.

Comment: I hope that my Question is clear enough.

Comment: Your question is very clear, and you could absolutely do this. [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: I tried setting up a variable equal to 0 and tried +1 but it hasn't had luck for me so far.

Comment: Show us your code! Just add it to your question, and we can help you with a solution.

Comment: Your code is indeed a bit messy, but I don't see any code that relates to your problem at hand. When posting your code, try to give us as little code as necessary to understand the problem (see: [sscce](http://sscce.org/)). Could you edit your post to include just the section relevant to color-switching? (We don't need to see all the shapes stuff).

Comment: I tried a lot of stuff and don't know what to do for the problem. I accidentally backspaced out of it so here is the code.

Comment: recommended: [Seven Ways To Use Turtle](http://python-turtle-demo.googlecode.com/files/SevenWaysToUseTurtle-PyCon2009.pdf)

Comment: I'm sorry I just don't know what I am looking for in that PDF file.

Comment: I still need help on this task. Is there a way to increment through the list whenever I press a key?

Comment: There is a answer waiting for you to try. Please let us know if it helps achieve your goal.

Answer (score 1):

A fully fleshed out version of @jfs' repair of @Aesthete's example:

```
from turtle import Screen, Turtle
from itertools import cycle

shape_colors = ['red', 'blue', 'green', 'cyan', 'magenta', 'yellow', 'black']

def change_color(colors=cycle(shape_colors)):
    turtle.color(next(colors))

turtle = Turtle('turtle')
turtle.shapesize(5)  # large turtle for demonstration purposes

screen = Screen()
screen.onkey(change_color, 'c')
screen.listen()
screen.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
shape_color = ['red', 'blue', 'green'] # list of colors
idx = 0 # index for color list

# Callback for changing color
def changecolor():
    idx = (idx+1) % len(shape_color) # Increment the index within the list bounds
    fillcolor(shape_color[idx]) # Change the fill color

# Register the callback with a keypress.
screen.onkey(changecolor, "c")
```

Now everytime you press the `c` key, your **fill color** will change, cycling through the list you defined.

Comment: it will raise UnboundLocalError. You could use: `changecolor = lambda colors=itertools.cycle(shape_color): fillcolor(next(colors))`

Comment: Great answer, if you submit that I'll remove mine.